# R: Assigning vectors from a list of vectors as a value of the column in a data frame from a list of data frames

Tags: r, list

I have two lists of equal length: one is a list of data frames, another is a list of vectors, such that a length of a each vector coincides with the number of rows in a respective data frame of the first list. I want to assign vectors from the second list as a value of the first column in each data frame. It would probably be easier to explain with the code bellow:

```
for (i in seq_along(data)){
   data[[c(i, 1)]] = links[[i]]
                         }
```

, where `data` is a list of data frames, and `links` is a list of vectors. While this code works fine, and speedwise there is no particular need to avoid `for` loops, I wonder whether there is any other way to perform the same action without `for`?

Comment: Please include the output of `dput(data)` and `dplut(links)`, or minimal representative examples of each object.

Comment: `c(i,1)` is a vector, but `[[` only works with scalars as far as I know.

Comment: @nrussell , thanks, will do the next time.

Answer (score 2):

Since `data`and `links` have the same lengths, and you are replacing one-for-one, `Map()` and/or `mapply()` would be a good choice. Using the data from the other answer,

```
data <- list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), data.frame(a = 10:14, b = 15:19))
links <- list(7:9, 20:24)
```

You can do

```
Map("[<-", data, 1, value = links)
# [[1]]
#   a b
# 1 7 4
# 2 8 5
# 3 9 6
#
# [[2]]
#    a  b
# 1 20 15
# 2 21 16
# 3 22 17
# 4 23 18
# 5 24 19
```

Although only the R gods know how safe this is. It would be safer to use an anonymous function.

```
Map(function(x, y, z) { x[y] <- z; x }, data, 1, links)
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about `Map()` and `mapply()`, nice addition @RichardScriven. Although I'd like to point out that `Map()` is a wrapper around `mapply()`, `mapply()` is a wrapper around `sapply()`, and `sapply()` is a wrapper around `lapply()`, so this reduces to the same code, albeit certainly with an improvement in concision and elegance over the direct `lapply()` call I gave in my answer.

Comment: It's not really the same code though. You are using `<<-` which overwrites the original data, and it's not necessary to do that.  It's also a bit dangerous.  Plus  `mapply()` is not a wrapper around `sapply()`.  It enters the C code at `.Internal(mapply())`.  There is no reference to `sapply()` at all in `mapply()`. But I see your point.

Comment: Actually my use of `<<-` corresponds more with what the OP wants to do; the code in his question also overwrites the original data (albeit via `=`). But I just assumed that, for your solution, you could completely overwrite the original data by assigning the return value of your `Map()` call to the original variable, i.e. `data <- Map(...)`, so I didn't see this difference as significant.

Comment: Well yes, but it wouldn't be overwritten if you called the result something else, like `data2 <- Map(...)`

Comment: Aha, right you are: "mapply is a multivariate *version* of sapply" (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html). I took that to mean it's a wrapper, but it's not. Good point.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! `Map` \ `mapply` is what I was after. However I failed to find any documentation on `Map`: is there any? Is it equivalent to `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=TRUE`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is already separated into independent list components, there is no way to do this operation without some kind of loop, hidden or explicit. This is because it is impossible to operate on multiple independent list components in any kind of vectorized or monolithic way; the nature of a list is a sequence of (allowably) heterogeneous objects which cannot be accessed as a unit.

You can replace the for-loop with the hidden loop in `lapply()`, but there isn't much point in going to the trouble:

```
l1 <- list(data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6), data.frame(a=10:14,b=15:19) );
l2 <- list(7:9, 20:24 );
invisible(lapply(seq_along(l1), function(i) l1[[i]][,1] <<- l2[[i]] ));
l1;
## [[1]]
##   a b
## 1 7 4
## 2 8 5
## 3 9 6
## 
## [[2]]
##    a  b
## 1 20 15
## 2 21 16
## 3 22 17
## 4 23 18
## 5 24 19
```

Alternatively, you can completely restructure your data, either temporarily or permanently, but this is obviously somewhat outside the scope of your question. For example, here's a way to temporarily `rbind()`/`c()` the inputs that allows performing the first-column replacement as a unit, before `split()`ting back into the original list form (it should also be noted that I had to use `sapply()` once anyway just to get the lengths to use for splitting the aggregated data.frame back into separate data.frames) (it should also be noted that this will only work if all data.frames have the same number and names of columns):

```
unname(split(transform(do.call(rbind,l1),a=do.call(c,l2)),rep(seq_along(l2),sapply(l2,length))));
## [[1]]
##   a b
## 1 7 4
## 2 8 5
## 3 9 6
## 
## [[2]]
##    a  b
## 4 20 15
## 5 21 16
## 6 22 17
## 7 23 18
## 8 24 19
```

As you can see, a for-loop is clearly more straightforward and sensible than these alternatives.